Access Private DNS of Internal ALB and RDS Across AWS Accounts Without Network Connectivity
Title:
Access Private DNS of Internal ALB and RDS Across AWS Accounts Without Network Connectivity
Body:
I have a setup with two AWS accounts: Account-A and Account-B.
In Account-A:

I have a private VPC (VPC-A) where I created:

An internal Application Load Balancer (ALB).
A private RDS instance located in private subnets.



In Account-B:

There is no VPC Peering, Direct Connect, or PrivateLink connection between the two accounts.

Issue:
Despite the lack of network connectivity, I am able to resolve the private DNS names of the internal ALB and the private RDS instance from Account-B.
I have checked the following:

Security Groups: Ensured no inbound traffic is allowed in the VPC-A subnets.
Network ACLs: Confirmed that there are no rules allowing access from Account-B to Account-A.
IG/NATGW: The vpc-A does not have IG or NAT gw.
In vpc-A -  DNS hostnames-Enabled and DNS resolution-Enabled

Questions:

How is it possible to resolve the private DNS of resources in Account-A from Account-B without any established network connection?
What mechanisms in AWS allow for this behavior, and what are the implications for security?
Is there a way to restrict DNS resolution of private resources in Account-A from Account-B without implementing network connectivity?

Additional Context:

I understand that private DNS resolution typically requires network connectivity, but I'm observing unexpected behavior.
Any insights or explanations on this would be greatly appreciated!



Seems like the DNS for private resources is public by design: https://repost.aws/questions/QU0-9lunTWRB2BdwkCRln9uw/should-a-non-public-rds-instance-have-a-publicly-resolvable-dns-name
